# Loading Image and Applying it to Image Texture Node

Tags: python, scripting, interface, node-editor, add-on

I am coding an add-on, in which I want the user to select an image using a File Browser of a Custom panel. Then the Image selected is applied to the "object's active material's - Image Texture Node".

I have used this code to create a File Browser in the custom Panel. But when an image is selected, it does not get imported in Blender.
This is the code:

```
Img_path= StringProperty(name="Browse for an Image:",attr="custompath",description="Image file path",maxlen= 1024,subtype='FILE_PATH',default= "",update=update_texture)
```

That update_texture is defined to set the Image to the Image Texture node. But I don't know how to do it!

Also I need help in making only image files available when File Browser shows up. Thanks in advance....

Comment: The [import image as planes](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_import_images_as_planes.py) does most of what you are after, where it creates new objects for each image you could adjust it to alter an existing object material.